# http post from firefox extension to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http, firefox-addon

I want to be able to send a simple **http post** from my **firefox extension** to my **ASP.NET** application. From the client side, I have used *XMLHTTPRequest* by sending the post with the url: http://localhost:15227 which is the url on my ASP.NET app.

What do I need to do to receive a remote request from ASP.NET please?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/xmlhttpreq.html) from Apple has a pretty good example of how to send/receive data using a raw XmlHttpReqeust object (as opposed to a JavaScript library).

You can get the value of the response from the [responseText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534369%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property once you know the response came back successfully.  Specifically take a look at where the `processReqChange` function is defined, your code will go in there (or your equivalent of that function).

---

If you want to explore JavaScript frameworks, take a look at how much less code you need if you use [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (for example).